# Solving vector calculation question

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

A spaceship is traveling through space at constant speed along a straight line that passes through the points $A = (-3,-8,-6)$ and $B = (-8,-4,-3)$.

The star Gliese $061$, located at $P = (-12,0,0)$ is orbited by an inhabited planet. If the spaceship passes within distance $1/2$ of this star, the inhabitants will detect it. Is the spaceship detected?

I'm not sure how to solve this question as usually I get two vector functions which I can then equate.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you know how to calculate the distance from a point to a straight line?

Comment: I don't know how to calculate the distance from a point to a straight line.

Comment: Then I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) may help you.

Comment: The information from wikipedia is a bit overwhelming for me to comprehend, would you be able to show me how I should solve this question?

Comment: Maybe you are not aware, but you should provide your attempts so that we can better help you. Otherwise, your question will probably be closed.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure how to even attempt it.

Comment: Well, once you have a point $A = (-3,-8,-6)$ and a direction $v = B - A = (-5,4,3)$, you have a line $L(t) = A + tv = (-3 - 5t,-8 + 4t, -6 + 3t)$. Once you have the line $L(t)$ and the point $P = (-12,0,0)$, you can determine the distance between them.

Comment: Do I equate L(t) and P to find t?

Comment: My favourite way of determining the distance in $\mathbb R^3$ between a point and a line is the [last method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Another_vector_formulation) in the wikipedia page suggested by APCorreia: find any vector joining the point $P$ & the line $AB$, and the unit direction vector of $AB$, then the (shortest) distance between $P$ and $AB$ is the magnitude of their cross product.

Comment: See if you can show that $C=(-12.5, -0.4, -0.3)$ is on the line $AB$, and that $PC$ is perpendicular to $AB$.

Comment: You might find this [sketch](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9z0FPwyAUB_A7n-JlHsazrVtbXfTQk_G-u_EAlG4kFRiwGv30PjQ2y5qYlBTe_wcPEnQwicDXaY1M5IVWyQXOq7aE6pHGDpHJyyAX72m0FPjLoG5K2NJHdTZRwCVUIPDOuvAuRvOle47sBl5OZ5GMs-AGGI3VICQbiAsoIMEtTIzQ8-iijgm8MzYBYSEhOfBMkRx46uqnTTyFxJvczUeqPmxZOhqa1Du2p18-u-05F-XPBsoQS1BudKFbyfGsV0iu6H57kHzNzCAMLoABYyEGYQ-a086ixrcSIr2h83HT_HuMn-HMgu6vVb6WxCVVn8JeW7Vkh6D17P5eSp0VLkg8ug--x289Y4xO&lang=sage) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

consider a similar/simpler  problem $A=(-2,-5)$, $B=(9,4)$ and $P=(0,1)$, where $A$,$B$ and $P$ mean the same as in your question and the detection radius is still $\frac{1}{2}$

You can parameterise the path of the spaceship, in terms of the time, $t$, and we say it arrives at time $t=1$, as $\vec{r}=(11t-2,9t-5)$.

Now the distance, $d$, from point $p_1=(p_{1x},p_{1y})$ to $p_2=(p_{2x},p_{2y})$ is
$$D=\sqrt{(p_{1x}-p_{2x})^2+(p_{1y}-p_{2y})^2}$$

so the distance from $\vec{r}$ to $p$ is
$$D(t)=\sqrt{(11t-2-0)^2+(9t-5-1)^2}=\sqrt{(11t-2)^2+(9t-6)^2}$$

So we can differentiate the expression for $D(t)$, with respect to $t$,
$$\frac{d}{dt}D(t)=\frac{202t-76}{\sqrt{(11t-2)^2+(9t-6)^2}}$$

so the closest distance is when $\frac{d}{dt}D(t)=0$, therefore $0=202(t)-76$, therefore $t=\frac{76}{202}=\frac{38}{101}$ and $D_{min}=D(\frac{38}{101})=3.3773$.

Therefore it is greater than the detection distance.

hopefully that helps

(I'll see if i can include a method that doesn't use calculus).

Comment: @PM2Ring, thanks, i'll correct it now. After years of maths you'd expect i'd know that $(9)(6)≠36$, :)